# Is there a method to get the end/beginning coordinates of a line shape in Office.js?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I am trying to place a textbox at the end/beginning points of some line shapes and can't seem to figure out how to get the coordinates of the line to place the textbox shape at. I tried using the connectBeginShape method but it doesn't seem to work with textboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `shape.left` and `shape.top`, with this 2 APIs, you can get the coordinates of the starting point, and you can use `shape.width` and `shape.height` to calculate the endpoint coordinate together with the starting point.

Here is a sample code for a reference.

```
 await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const shapes = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Shapes").shapes;
    var line = shapes.getItem("StraightLine");
    line.load();
    await context.sync();
    var x1 = line.left;
    var y1 = line.top;
    var x2 = line.left + line.width;
    var y2 = line.top + line.height;
    console.log("X1=" + x1 + ";Y1=" + y1);
    console.log("X2=" + x2 + ";Y2=" + y2);
    await context.sync();
  });
```

Please note: `shape.left` will return a number, which is the distance, in points, from the left side of the shape to the left side of the worksheet.

Comment: Does this take into account the rotation of a line?

Comment: I think so, you may need to call shape.left APIs again to get the coordinates

Comment: Raymond do you think you could take a look at my most recent question? Much appreciated.